# jquery event not fire after ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have below js which the event is not fire after ajax append the content

```
$(".item").mouseenter(function(){ $(this).children('.delete').show(); });

$(".item").mouseleave(function(){ $(this).children('.delete').hide(); });

$(".delete").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide(); });

$("#add").click(function(){
  action = 'addItem';
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/echo/json/",
    data: 'action='+action,
    cache: false,
    success: function(json){
        $(".main").append('<div class="item"><div class="content"> content new </div><div class="delete"> delete </div></div>');
    }
  });
});
```

Please check out the jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/3j5L2/19/

How do I ensure no matter how many item I added in, the mouseenter and mouseleave event get fired?

Comment: Or one of [the others..](https://www.google.com/#q=jquery+event+dynamic+element+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) with [jQuery's `on` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Event delegation refers to the process of using event propagation (bubbling) to handle events at a higher level in the DOM than the element on which the event originated. It allows us to attach a single event listener for elements that exist now or in the future.

```
$('.main').on('mouseenter', '.item', function() {
    ...
});
```

Assuming your `.main` element isn't dynamically created, this event listener will be assigned to the `.main` element and will only trigger when the event occurs to that specific descendant.

Answer (score 0):

You need [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for binding events to dynamically added elements:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$(".main").on('click','.delete',function(){
   $(this).parent().hide();
});
```